# Is there a function in python that could help me have all the values related in one row instead of multiple

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want top present the values in this data frame for each year on the same row.Like for 2019,I want only 1 row for 2019 that has all the corresponding values.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJtpF.png)

```
    Year    Profits of A    Profits of B    Profits of C    Profits of D    Profits of E
0   1999    200.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   2000    220.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   2001    240.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   2002    260.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   2003    224.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ...
58  2018    NaN NaN NaN NaN 123.25
59  2019    NaN 157.5   NaN NaN NaN
60  2019    NaN NaN 99.0    NaN NaN
61  2019    NaN NaN NaN 82.8    NaN
62  2019    NaN NaN NaN NaN 102.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just group by year and sum:

```py
import pandas as pd
import io

data = io.StringIO(
"""Index    Year    "Profits of A"    "Profits of B"    "Profits of C"    "Profits of D"    "Profits of E"
0   1999    200.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   2000    220.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   2001    240.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   2002    260.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   2003    224.0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
58  2018    NaN NaN NaN NaN 123.25
59  2019    NaN 157.5   NaN NaN NaN
60  2019    NaN NaN 99.0    NaN NaN
61  2019    NaN NaN NaN 82.8    NaN
62  2019    NaN NaN NaN NaN 102.00""")

df = pd.read_table(data, index_col=0, delim_whitespace=True)
df2 = df.groupby('Year').sum().reset_index()
print(df2)
#    Year  Profits of A  Profits of B  Profits of C  Profits of D  Profits of E
# 0  1999         200.0           0.0           0.0           0.0          0.00
# 1  2000         220.0           0.0           0.0           0.0          0.00
# 2  2001         240.0           0.0           0.0           0.0          0.00
# 3  2002         260.0           0.0           0.0           0.0          0.00
# 4  2003         224.0           0.0           0.0           0.0          0.00
# 5  2018           0.0           0.0           0.0           0.0        123.25
# 6  2019           0.0         157.5          99.0          82.8        102.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
x3.groupby('Year').max()
```

Assuming only one non-null value will be present for each column per year